# Delete all portlets site-wide in Plone

Tags: plone, portlet

What's the best (or simplest) way to delete portlets site-wide in plone 4.x?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. what do you mean with "old" portlets? do you mean that it's a plone site that has been upgraded to 4.x with portlet that are not compatible anymore with plone4.x?

Comment: Sorry for this, I mean all portlets - all currently assigned portlets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If you have a small amount of local assigned portlets I suggest the manual way. If you have a complex assignment of local portlets you could take this way:

1- create a [browser view](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/five-zope3-walkthrough/browser-view-1) linked to the site root

2- add this:

```
from Products.Five import BrowserView
from Products.CMFCore.utils import getToolByName
from zope.component import getMultiAdapter
from plone.portlets.interfaces import IPortletManager
from plone.portlets.interfaces import IPortletAssignmentMapping
from plone.portlets.interfaces import ILocalPortletAssignable

class MyView(BrowserView):

    def __call__(self):
        ctool = getToolByName(self.context, 'portal_catalog')
        all_brains = ctool.searchResults()

        for i in all_brains:
            obj = i.getObject()
            if not ILocalPortletAssignable.providedBy(obj):
                continue
            for manager_name in ('plone.leftcolumn','plone.rightcolumn'):
                manager = getUtility(IPortletManager, name=manager_name)
                assignment_mapping = getMultiAdapter((obj, manager), 
                                                       IPortletAssignmentMapping)
                    for i in assignment_mapping.keys():
                        del assignment_mapping['assignment_mapping']
```

Usually retrieving all objects is not a good thing, so you should evaluate carefully the amount of contents and local portlers. That said, this way is a bit aggressive but it will do the job.

Comment: Instead of creating a view, you could just run that code in the debug console too.

Comment: even if i personally prefer browserviews, you are right, that's an option :) . In this case, in the end just remember to import the transaction module and run transaction.commit().

Answer (score 1):

I think you made a small typo:

```
del assignment_mapping['assignment_mapping']
```

should be:

```
del assignment_mapping[i]
```

Comment: And this should be a comment in Giacomo's answer and not an answer by itself.